# Firebase Error 400 Sending HttpPost message

Tags: java, android, firebase, http-post, firebase-cloud-messaging

I´m trying to send a messaje from a `Java` server to a specific `Android` device but it returns me an error: `400 Bad Request`.

The key of the app is ok, due to I´had been trying with other wrong keys until founded in the `Firebase` Console

The code is:

```
    public static void sendMensaje(){

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "zzz Empieza");
        String respuestaString = new String("OK \n");
        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Authorization", "key="+" AAA...K0ynKNJN");

            String mensajeJSONEnString = buildNotificationMessage().toString();
            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(mensajeJSONEnString,"UTF-8");
            post.setEntity(stringEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(responseCode == 200 ) {
                respuestaString = "OK!";
            } else {
                String respuestaString2 = new String();
                if (responseCode == 500) {
                    respuestaString2 ="Error interno del servidor, prueba más tarde.\n";
                } else if (responseCode == 503) {
                    respuestaString2 ="Servidor no disponible temporalmente, prueba más tarde.\n";
                } else if (responseCode == 401) {
                    respuestaString2 ="La API Key utilizada no es válida.\n";
                }
                respuestaString = new StringBuilder(respuestaString2).append(responseCode).append(" ").append(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()).toString();
                System.out.println(respuestaString);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("return true");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "zzz " + "FIN");
    }

    private static JsonObject buildNotificationMessage() {
        JsonObject jNotification = new JsonObject();
        jNotification.addProperty("title", "TITLE");
        jNotification.addProperty("body", "BODY");

        JsonObject jMessage = new JsonObject();
        jMessage.add("notification", jNotification);
        jMessage.addProperty("to", "e1ltVa_...CVOKg6D5");

        JsonObject jFcm = new JsonObject();
        jFcm.add("message", jMessage);

        return jFcm;
    }
```

Where is the problem? the way I prepare the JSON?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posts to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` use the [Legacy HTTP Server Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).  The JSON for the request does not use `message` as the root.  That was introduced with the [HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_post_request).

Make these changes:

```
private static JsonObject buildNotificationMessage() {
    JsonObject jNotification = new JsonObject();
    jNotification.addProperty("title", "TITLE");
    jNotification.addProperty("body", "BODY");

    JsonObject jMessage = new JsonObject();
    jMessage.add("notification", jNotification);
    jMessage.addProperty("to", "e1ltVa_...CVOKg6D5");

    //JsonObject jFcm = new JsonObject();  // <= NOT NEEDED
    //jFcm.add("message", jMessage);  // <= NOT NEEDED

    return jMessage;  // <= CHANGED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use firebaseId and not app id, reinstall your app, and set a breakpoint in FirebaseRegistrationService, this service is launched once in the application life, and it's only job is to get firebase token id. You get an error 400 because your token is not the right one.

```
public class FirebaseCloudRegistrationService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    String TAG = "FirebaseNotification";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

  breakpoint -->  storeRegistrationId(this, refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: That´s the Token of the Android device,no? I had taken it in that way and harcoded to test

Comment: That's a bad idea, each time you reinstall/clear cache your app, the token change, instead store it in SharedPreference

Comment: Also if you test on multiple device, it change